# Raspberry Pi Zero W not interacting with GSM HAT

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, uart, gpio

I have Raspberry Pi Zero W and [this](https://www.waveshare.com/gsm-gprs-gnss-hat.htm) hat.
[image: My Setup]

##### I did the following things:

- disabled login shell through serial in rasp-config
- enabled serial port hardware in rasp-config
- removed `console=serial0` in /boot/cmdline.txt
- added lines to `/boot/config.txt`:

  - `enable_uart=1`
  - `dtoverlay=pi-miniuart-bt`

Then I restart the RPI.

##### Problem...

But when I do `sudo minicom -D /dev/serial0` (serial1, ttyS0, and ttyAMA0 doesnt work either), it says its offline...

Am I missing something?

##### Here are all the files that might be interesting:

[cmdline.txt](https://pastebin.com/8AMCLHvn)

[config.txt](https://pastebin.com/0LhqeyCD)

Comment: Isn't it better to ask a question here? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

To switch the bluetooth controller to the mini-UART so you can use the PL011 UART to communicate with your HAT, [you should specify](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/boot/overlays)

```
dtoverlay=miniuart-bt
```

Alternatively you can use

```
dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt
```

which was kept around for backwards compatibility.